Optimal Strategy For Mastermind-Like Game
A few days ago my brother challenged me to a game in which we both pick a 4 digit number and type it into a google doc. We then exchange guesses to find the others number. If we have a number in the right place, (ie. green in wordle), the other says 1, but not which; if se have two they say two, but not which two, et cetera. If you have all four, of course, you win. If you have a right number in the wrong spot (ie. yellow in wordle), the other doesn’t have to say anything.

Ex: if my brother’s number is 2841, and I guess 3864, he just says one, and that’s all the info I get.

I was wondering if there is an optimal strategy to have better odds at winning. Together we have tried multiple strategies, such as starting with 0000, then 1111, then 2222, and we stop once we know all four digits but not their places (You are allowed to choose a number with the same digit twice or more), from there, there is <25 options and I know how to do so.. There are many other strategies we thought of, but I was wondering: Would there be a way to maximise the chances of winning, and if so what is it?
Thanks in advance for helping me beat my brother! 
